# R function for sorting in Python Zip like structure

Tags: r

I have a vector:

```
dput(pos)

c(2000L, 2020L, 2020L, 2040L, 2060L, 2080L, 2100L, 2120L, 2140L, 2160L, 2180L, 
2200L, 2220L, 2240L, 2260L, 2280L, 2300L, 2320L, 2340L, 2360L,  2380L,
2400L, 2420L, 2440L, 2460L, 2480L, 2500L, 2520L, 2540L,  2560L, 2580L,
2600L, 2620L, 2640L, 2660L, 2680L, 2700L, 2720L,  2740L, 2760L, 2780L,
2800L, 2820L, 2840L, 2860L, 2880L, 2900L,  2920L, 2940L, 2960L, 2980L)
```

I would like to sort `pos` in a way such that I get the following vector:

`2000, 2980, 2020, 2960, 2040, 2940` and so on.

I wrote a function:

```
for (i in seq_along(pos)){  
el1 <- min(range(pos))   
el2 <- max(range(pos))   
res <- rbind(el1, el2)  
pos <- pos[!pos == c(el1, el2)]}
```

Needless to say it is not giving me the desired `res` vector. I understand I am not invoking `i` anywhere in my loop, how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do 2000, 2980 as the first values of sorted `pos` come from? The minimum of `pos` is 2020 and the maximum is 2960.

Comment: Please check now

Comment: I edited the syntax because the `>` characters were unnecessary and made it difficult to paste into an R console. Looks OK now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reverse vector and combine with original selecting one or another based on even/odd sequence:

```
  newdata <- data.frame(cbind(dat=data, rev=c(1, rev(data)[- length(data)]), n=seq(1:length(data)))) %>%
  mutate(res=ifelse(n%%2==1, dat, rev)) %>%
  select(res)
```

Comment: I love these alternate solutions but always wonder how to fix what was missing in my approach

Answer (score 0):

```
pos = c(2000L, 2020L, 2040L, 2060L, 2080L, 2100L, 2120L, 2140L, 2160L, 2180L, 
  2200L, 2220L, 2240L, 2260L, 2280L, 2300L, 2320L, 2340L, 2360L,  2380L,
  2400L, 2420L, 2440L, 2460L, 2480L, 2500L, 2520L, 2540L,  2560L, 2580L,
  2600L, 2620L, 2640L, 2660L, 2680L, 2700L, 2720L,  2740L, 2760L, 2780L,
  2800L, 2820L, 2840L, 2860L, 2880L, 2900L,  2920L, 2940L, 2960L)

n = round(length(pos)/2)+1

pos2 = rep(0,(2*(n)-1))

pos2[2*(1:n)] = pos[2*(n:1)-1]
pos2[2*(1:n)-1] = pos[2*(1:n)]
```